# strcpy in C is illegally altering the copied string?

Tags: c, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a really mysterious behavior I can't get around.

I'm trying to edit the string of one variable and then copy again to the source. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char word[100] = "1 hash";
    char* sp = malloc(100);
    sp = strchr(word, ' ');
    sp++;
    // the "bug" still happens with strcpy  instead of strncpy
    strncpy(word, sp, 100);

    printf("%s\n", word);
}
```

The output is:

```
hhsh
```

It should've been `hash`.

The weird thing is that "1 hash" is the only string I found that this bug happens. All the other strings I tried gave me the expected output. For example: `"1 huhanh" -> huhanh` or `"3 a h c" -> a h c`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You leak the allocated memory on the next line.

Comment: Pedro Vinícius, best to avoid using `strncpy()` until you understand why it is troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior. The `malloc` pointer is ignored.

So, when you do the `strcpy`, `sp` and `word` are part of the *same* string.

This is UB. Which means it may segfault. It may work. It may produce incorrect results.

In this instance, we can't predict the order of the fetching of the bytes and the storing. With certain sequences, it will [appear to] work. With others, we may fetch a byte that was *not* an input but an *output* from the previous byte.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    char word[100] = "1 hash";
    char *copy = malloc(100);

    char *sp = strchr(word, ' ');
    sp++;

    strncpy(copy, sp, 100);

    printf("%s\n", copy);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks for the answer. I indeed didn't realized they were all part of the same string. In the example code u provided, does the pointer `sp` still have to exist? –
> Pedro Vinícius

Yes, because it is where you are copying *from*. Notice that you get the pointer from `strchr`. Then, you *increment* it. It is this *updated* value that becomes the source address.

This *is* clean code.

But, you *could* do:

```
strncpy(copy, strchr(word, ' ') + 1, 100);
```

But, I wouldn't do this. IMO, it's "too cute". The original `sp` code will execute just as fast. And, it's easier to read. And it let's you do some error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    char word[100] = "1 hash";
    char *copy = malloc(100);

    char *sp = strchr(word, ' ');

    if (sp != NULL) {
        sp++;
        strncpy(copy, sp, 100);
    }
    else
        *copy = 0;

    printf("%s\n", copy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I indeed didn't realized they were all part of the same string. In the example code u provided, does the pointer `sp` still have to exist?

I have decided to use `memmove` as others have suggested.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yup.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* sp = malloc(100);
```

The problem is that this allocated memory is not used, at all. `strchr` returns a pointer to a character *in the original string*. And according to the [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy)

> destination and source shall not overlap

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do u have any insight on why did this behavior only happened with this specific string? Other strings I tried had some overlapping, but still dindn't show the same behavior. Is that because it's undefined behavior on C when they overlap, or something else?

Comment: And, what would u recommend as alterations to the source code so the behavior would not be like the one I observed? Like, instead of `hhsh`, it gave me `hash`?

Comment: `Is that because it's undefined behavior on C when they overlap` Yes. Anything could happen.

Comment: `And, what would u recommend as alterations to the source code so the behavior would not be like the one I observed?` You could just use `sp` instead of `hash`. Or using a `memmove` which _does_ work with overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
char* sp = malloc(100);
sp = strchr(word, ' ');
```

allocates some memory then leaks it away. sp ends up pointed into the 'word' on the stack